# how to delete Temp files in robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Process    
*** Test Cases ***
Temp files clear
    Run Process    del    %TEMP%    /*.*    /s    /f    /q    

----------------------------------------------------------------
FAIL    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am using Windows10.
how to resolve this error?

Comment: I wonder which part of it was giving the FileNotFoundError.. By the way, `%TEMP%` and `/*.*` should not be two arguments - in the CLI you'd pass them as a single, concatenated string.

Comment: @TodorMinakov its "del" .. its built in into windows shell so when you run that "as process", there is no such command like del.bat del.cmd del.com or del.exe which then triggers FileNotFoundError

Comment: Yes, I'm aware what `del` is in Windows :), that's why I said it's strange to me this exception is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rasjani's comment actually got me thinking - try the `Run Process` call with `shell=${True}`.

```
Run Process    del    %TEMP%/*.*    /s    /f    /q     shell=${True}
```

The comment has reminded me something [from the official docs of `subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor):

> On Windows with shell=True, the COMSPEC environment variable specifies the default shell. The only time you need to specify shell=True on Windows is when the command you wish to execute is built into the shell (e.g. dir or copy). You do not need shell=True to run a batch file or console-based executable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Remove File` from the OperatingSystem](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#Remove%20File) library for the same purpose:

```
Remove File    ${TEMPDIR}${/}*.*
```

Comment: Getting error with this 'Remove File':
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\0cd8464a-9ae8-4621-a939-1317b426b8fe.tmp'

Comment: Yes, that's quite often when deleting temp files; wrap it in exception handling - run keyword and ignore error for example, and deal with it however seems right to you.